# How to invoke Webhook as part of ADF pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, webhooks

I am building an ADF pipeline, requirement is to invoke the Webhook service as part of Azure. Can someone please help me how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity)

Answer (score 0):

There is an activity specifically for that: Web hook activity
[image]